# Меняется значение переменной главного кода в функции модуля

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

**Вот главный код, меняется переменная 'a' после вызова функции 'zad1'**

```
program lab5;

uses zad;

var
  a, z1: matr;

begin
  vvod(f, a);
  vivod(f1, a);
  z1 := zad1(a);
  vivod(f1, a);
  vivod(f1, z1);
end.
```

**Вот код модуля 'zad'**

```
unit zad;

interface

type
  mas = Array of real;
  matr = Array of mas;

var 
  f, f1: text;

function zad1(arr: matr): matr;
function zad1_str(arr: mas): mas;
procedure vvod(var f: text; var arr: matr);
procedure vvod1(var f: text; var arr: mas; m: integer);
procedure vivod(var f:text; arr: matr);
procedure vivod1(var f: text; arr: mas);

implementation

procedure vvod1;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  setlength(arr, m); 
  for i := 0 to arr.Length - 1 do
  read(f, arr[i]);
  readln(f);
end;

procedure vvod;
var
  n, m, i: integer;
begin
  readln(n);
  readln(m);
  setlength(arr, n);
  for i := 0 to arr.Length - 1 do
    vvod1(f, arr[i], m);
end;

function zad1_str: mas;
var
   i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to arr.Length - 1 do
    if arr[i] > 0 then arr[i] := 1
    else arr[i] := 0;
  result := arr;
end;

function zad1: matr;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to arr.Length - 1 do
    arr[i] := zad1_str(arr[i]);
  result := arr
end;

procedure vivod1;
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to arr.Length - 1do
    write(f, arr[i], ' ');
  writeln(f);
end;

procedure vivod;
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to arr.Length - 1 do
    vivod1(f, arr[i]);
  writeln(f);
end;

initialization

  assign(f, 't1.txt');
  reset(f);
  assign(f1, 'log.txt');
  rewrite(f1);

finalization
  close(f);
  close(f1);

end.
```

**И содержимое файла 't1.txt'**

```
1 2 4 7
4 3 7 4
0 8 9 2
```

При старте программы нужно ввести количество строк (n), затем количество столбцов (m). В данном случае 3 и 4.

**Вот результат, который выводится в файл 'log.txt'**

```
1 2 4 7 
4 3 7 4 
0 8 9 2 

1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 

1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1
```

Comment: Все нормально. `а1` - это указатель.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Динамические массивы (в отличие от обычных) - это указатели. Вы передаёте в функцию указатель, а работаете с данными по этому адресу. Неудивительно, что данные меняются в исходной переменной, которая указывает на тот же адрес.

Чтобы этого не происходило необходимо перед обработкой скопировать данные и работать уже с копией этих данных, например так:

```
procedure zad1_str(arr: mas);
var
   i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to arr.Length - 1 do
    if arr[i] > 0 then arr[i] := 1
    else arr[i] := 0;
end;

function zad1(const arr: matr): matr;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := copy(arr, 0, arr.Length); // это для delphi, возможно в pabc.net массивы копируются по-другому.
  for i := 0 to result.Length - 1 do
    zad1_str(result[i]);
end;
```

P.S: Пример "из головы", паскаля под рукой нет.